# to collect the data in the text and the number in the text field

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

hi I want to add the number typed in the text widget to the number typed in textfield and show it in the same text. when it is first started, you want the text to have a value of 0, and then display its total value. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable maybe `firstNum = 0;`. Then create a text widget and assign this value like `Text("$firstNum")`. Then create a textField with a controller for example `secondNum`. When you enter a number in the text field and click on go or maybe in text field you can add onChange add the numbers `firstNum+int.parse(secondNum.text)` and assign it back to firstNum. Like `firstNum+= int.parse(secondNum.text);` Then setState. And make sure to change secondNum.text = "";